# Laravel Mail Debugging/Result

Tags: php, laravel, email

How can I see the result or errors from the Mail::send or queue methods in Laravel? I have used dd() on the method but I get either a 0 of which I am assuming is false to show the email failed to send. Is there any way to put it into a debug mode so I can see where the mailer is failing?

Comment: The mailer typically fails with an exception. Chances are it has nothing to do with PHP. What mail driver are you using?

Comment: SMTP with TLS encryption. I'm using the exact same settings as I did with PHPMailer of which works fine

Comment: With the SMTP driver any failure should trigger an immediate exception. Is it possible the emails are just in spam somewhere?

Comment: I checked in spam and inbox already

Comment: Is the SMTP server under your control, or is it something like Gmail?

Comment: Have you checked laravel logs?

Answer (score 5):

There are many mail drivers to use to send email, so many ways to debug. An approach would be to set:

```
'driver' => env('MAIL_DRIVER', 'log'),
```

in `config/mail.php` then quickly test if logging of mail works with:

```
Mail::raw('Text to e-mail', function($message)
{
  $message->from('user1@your-domain.tld', 'Laravel');
  $message->to('user2@your-domain.tld');
});
```

Then depending on 3rd party services and protocol, keep iterating. For instance to use SES, one would fill in these environment keys:

```
MAIL_DRIVER='ses'
SES_KEY='XXX'
SES_SECRET='YYY'
SES_REGION='ZZZ'
```

in `.env` and then in `config/services.php`:

```
'ses' => [
    'key' => env('SES_KEY'),
    'secret' => env('SES_SECRET'),
    'region' => env('SES_REGION'),
],
```

Use `php artisan tinker` and test with the `Mail::raw` code above. Also note that AWS requires its API to be connected by HTTPS or it will not send email.